# angular1 - Uncaught Error $injector:modulerr; angular-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to setup angular router.

I am following [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) tutorial.

I've installed angular and angular-router using bower and listed them in my html. Everything seems to be loading as expected (no 404 errors in console), so the scripts are there:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Miha Šušteršič</title>
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FOUNDATION -->
    <script src="assets/vendor/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ANGULAR -->
    <script src="assets/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- APP -->
    <script src="assets/js/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- FOUNDATION -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css">
    <!-- APP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="IntroductionApp">
    <!-- ANGULAR APP -->
    <portfolio></portfolio>
    <!-- FOUNDATION -->
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am trying to setup some basic routing. This is my app.js file (that gets compiled into angular.min.js):

```
// MAIN ANGULAR JS FILE
angular
    .module('IntroductionApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
        function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
            $locationProvider.hasPrefix('!');

            $routeProvider.
                when('/landing', {
                  templateUrl: 'templates/landing.html'
                }).
                when('/portfolio', {
                  templateUrl: 'templates/portfolio.html'
                }).
                otherwise('/landing');
            }
    ]);
```

Now I am getting the following error in the console:

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module IntroductionApp due to: TypeError: t.hasPrefix is
>   not a function
>       at http://localhost:48080/assets/js/app.min.js:1:108
>       at Object.invoke (http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:4709:19)
>       at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:4602:35)
>       at http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:4611:11
>       at forEach (http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:321:20)
>       at loadModules (http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:4592:5)
>       at createInjector (http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:4514:19)
>       at doBootstrap (http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:1751:20)
>       at bootstrap (http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:1772:12)
>       at angularInit (http://localhost:48080/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:1657:5)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=IntroductionApp&p1=…2F%2Flocalhost%3A48080%2Fassets%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1657%3A5)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should change to `angular.js` rather than `angular.min.js` to troubleshoot this problem, since the minified version doesn't give clear error messages.  Also, you can sometimes discover Dependency Injection errors by adding `ng-strict-di` to the element your `ng-app` is on.

Comment: updated main question with the error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its typo

```
$locationProvider.hasPrefix('!');
```

should be

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```